# VBA taking long time while applying Vlook up and formula

Tags: excel, vba

Macro is taking around 30-40 minutes while filling the formulas to all the rows.
Formulas need to apply around 20,000 rows. All the formulas are available in `Range("M1:P1")` and `Range("A1:C1")`.

```vb
Sub Position()
    Dim LR As Long

    Application.StatusBar = "Maro is running...."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Sheets("MR").Select
    LR = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Range("A1:C1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("A1:C" & LR)

    Sheets("CR").Select

    Range("M1:P1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("M1:P" & LR)

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Set SrchRng = Range("L:L")

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "30") > 0 Then
            cel.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Sumitomo"
        End If
    Next cel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Can someone advise why it is taking too much time.

Comment: Well, you are looping over more than a million rows, but even then it should not be 40 minutes.

Comment: `Set SrchRng = Range("L:L")` to `Set SrchRng = Range("L1:L" & LR)` would significantly limit the amount of cells looked at in the loop.  Could go even faster if you take that range as a variant array and loop through it

Comment: Thank you for the above code but still its taking same time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Problem:**

- Use of Select
- Looping over complete Column `L:L`

**Note: You are also using the same LR for both sheets.**

**Try it now:**

```
Sub Position()
    Dim LR As Long

    Application.StatusBar = "Maro is running...."
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    LR = Sheets("MR").UsedRange.Rows.Count
    Sheets("MR").Range("A1:C1").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("MR").Range("A1:C" & LR)

    Sheets("CR").Range("M1:P1").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("CR").Range("M1:P" & LR)

    Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range

    Set SrchRng = Sheets("CR").Range("L1:L" & Sheets("CR").UsedRange.Rows.Count)

    For Each cel In SrchRng
        If InStr(1, cel.Value, "30") > 0 Then
            cel.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Sumitomo"
        End If
    Next cel

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: All these improvements are correct, but I doubt they are related to the issue. Looping over the 1048576 rows takes less than 2 seconds on a boring office PC.

Comment: Thank you for the above code but still its taking same time

Comment: There maybe something wrong with the file. Can you share it so that I can have a look ?

Comment: I have tried removing   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic its running quicker, its taking long time only for calculation. is there any way to make it fast

Comment: But your code already have those lines first to set it as `Manual` and then in the end to set it as `Automatic`. So that should not be the case. Does your file have many formulas and links to other files ?

Answer (score 2):

Your code here loops through every cell in L:L range, that is almost an infinite loop, as it'll loop through maximum possible number of rows excel can support. Try only using used number of rows to decrese the number of for loop repetition. It'll slow down significantly.

```
Set SrchRng = Range("L1:L" & Cstr(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)) ' I Decreased this range

For Each cel In SrchRng
If InStr(1, cel.Value, "30") > 0 Then
    cel.Offset(0, 4).Value = "Sumitomo"
End If
Next cel
```

Comment: A loop that runs from `1 To 1048576` is... not intinite.

Comment: I said 'almost infinite'; it takes a lot of time to finish, I have accidentally done that and sometimes it throws overflow error if you are accumulating the cell values or using a recursive function. In real life, anything that is extremely higher than the required range can be considered infinite for practical purposes.

Comment: Thank you for the above code but still its taking same time.

Comment: I have tried removing   Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic its running quicker, its taking long time only for calculation. is there any way to make it fast